# How to get specific assignee of a story, subtask with a specific summary in JIRA?

Tags: jql

I am using JIRA version v8.5.9, where I am running the following query in its search option.

```
issuetype = "Sub task" AND assigned == 'xyz' and summary = '16.4'
```

Where `xyz` is a user. Basically what I am trying to achieve is: I am looking for all stories, sub-tasks whose assignee is `xyz` user along with its summary should contain 16.4 in it. When I am running this query it's not giving me any results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Last time I got help from @RavinderSingh13 can you please do help me here?

Comment: Is it only containing 16.4 OR it can contain anything else also in summary?

Comment: Yes, it could contain other strings as well, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown attempts, could you please try following query.

```
(issuetype = "Story" OR issuetype = "Sub task") AND  assignee = 'xyz' AND summary ~ "16.4"
```

***Explanation:***

- First thing first you need to use OR condition for having stories and sub tasks both to be catch here.
- Then you need to use `~` operator to search for string, since you mentioned you could have other than 16.4 string then we can't use `=` here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try using the contains `~` operator:

```
issuetype = "Sub task" AND assigned == 'xyz' and summary ~ '*16.4*'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Ravinder's answer giving me more accurate result